# Django - Update database value on drag and drop

Tags: javascript, django, drag-and-drop

I am creating TODO app, and I am trying to implemnt drag and drop using JavaScript.
I managed to create drag and drop feature but I don't know how to change and save tasks "category" (for example backlog to done) on drop.

Do I need to use JavaScript or is there some Django library that can help me?
If JS is necessary, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Since your action happens on the client side (in your browser), it means you have to use JavaScript to trigger the database change action.

But JavaScript does not have access to your backend database directly, that's why when you drop your card/task in another category, you want to handle that event and recognize in which category you have landed. (all this with JS)

Then you call your server API, via AJAX and you pass the task id and the new category to your backend side, where you have to update the database with new information.

I hope this was clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to poll the server, you could use WS. You need JavaScript to open the connection.

Install Django Channels
Install a broker(Redis)
Run the server in ASGI not WSGI.

I run Daphne behind Apache to handle WS-requests

> The WebSocket API is an advanced technology that makes it possible to open a two-way interactive communication session between the user's browser and a server. With this API, you can send messages to a server and receive event-driven responses without having to poll the server for a reply.

I use WS to send notification to all users on the same page if the DB have been changed. Your JavaScript could trigger Django that trigger DB via WS and also can send back and update your value on the page.